# Understanding docker compose port wiring for django, react app and haproxy

Tags: node.js, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I came across a docker-compose.yml which has following port configuration:

```
    wsgi: 
        ports: 
            - 9090  // ?? Is it by default mapped to host port 80 ??  

    nodejs 
            image: nodejs:myapp 
            ports: 
                - 9999:9999 
            environment: 
                BACKEND_API_URL: http://aa.bb.cc.dd:9854/api/ 

    haproxy 
        ports: 
            - 9854:80
```

I am trying to understand how the port wiring is happening here.

`nodejs` UI app settings needs to specify backend port which is `9854` here. This port is exposed by `haproxy` setting and is mapped to port `80`. I know that `wsgi` is a django backend app. From its `entrypoint.sh` (in PS below) and port specification in above `docker-compose.yml`, I get that django listens to port `9090`. But I am unable to get how this port `9090` maps to port `80` (which is then exposed by `haproxy` at `9854`, which in turn is specified in `BACKEND_API_URL` by `nodejs` settings).

**PS:**

Django wsgi app has following in `\wsgi\entrypoint.sh`:

```
    nohup gunicorn myapp.wsgi --bind "0.0.0.0:9090"
```

And nodejs react app has following in its `server.js` file:

```
    const port = process.env.PORT || 9999;
```

My whole docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - my_app_postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - type: tmpfs
              target: /dev/shm
              tmpfs:
                size: 536870912 # 512MB
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: my_app_db
            POSTGRES_USER: my_app
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_app123
        networks:
            - my_app_network

    redis:
        image: redis:6.2.4
        volumes:
            - my_app_redis_volume:/data
        networks:
            - my_app_network

    wsgi:
        image: wsgi:my_app3_stats
        volumes:
            - /my_app/frontend/static/
            - ./wsgi/my_app:/my_app
            - /my_app/frontend/clientApp/node_modules
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        ports:
            - 9090
        environment:
            C_FORCE_ROOT: 'true'
            SERVICE_PORTS: 9090
        networks:
            - my_app_network
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 1
                delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s

    nodejs:
        image: nodejs:my_app3_stats
        volumes:
            - ./nodejs/frontend:/frontend
            - /frontend/node_modules
        depends_on:
            - wsgi
        ports:
            - 9999:9999 
        environment:
            BACKEND_API_URL: http://aa.bb.cc.dd:9854/api/ 
        networks:
            - my_app_network

    nginx:
        image: isiq/nginx-brotli:1.21.0
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
            - ./wsgi/my_app:/my_app:ro
            - my_app_nginx_volume:/var/log/nginx/
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        networks:
            - my_app_network
            
    haproxy:
        image: haproxy:2.3.9
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        depends_on:
            - wsgi
            - nodejs
            - nginx
        ports:
            - 9854:80
        networks:
            - my_app_network
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]

volumes:
    my_app_postgres_volume:
    my_app_redis_volume:
    my_app_nginx_volume:

networks:
    my_app_network:
        driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 0):

On your host, there are three ports visible:

1. `http://aa.bb.cc.dd:9854` forwards to port 80 on the `haproxy` container.
2. `http://aa.bb.cc.dd:9999` forwards to port 9999 on the `nodejs` container.
3. The port shown by `docker-compose port wsgi 9090` forwards to port 9090 on the `wsgi` container.

You don't discuss the HAProxy configuration at all, but it is presumably configured to listen on port 80, and that may be the missing bit of configuration you're looking for.

Between these three containers (so not visible to your front-end application), assuming you don't have any `networks:` blocks in the Compose file, there are three obvious URLs: `http://haproxy:80` (or just `http://haproxy`), `http://nodejs:9999`, and `http://wsgi:9090` connect to their respective containers.  Note that these use the "normal" ports for their service, and not the remapped port for `haproxy` or the randomly-chosen port for `wsgi`.

I'm guessing the HAProxy container is configured to do some sort of path-based routing to one or the other of the other containers.  If you have this setup, you might be able to configure your React application to not include a host name in the URL at all (`BACKEND_API_URL: /api/`), which will make it easier to deploy.  You do not need the `ports:` for connections between containers, and if you don't want a caller to be able to reach the back-end services without going via the proxy, you can delete their `ports:` blocks.

Comment: Hi David, sorry I felt providing only relevant part of docker compose with simplify. But seems that it lacks context. Now, I have added docker compose file at the end of orginal post, in case it brings more light ...

Comment: The URLs to communicate between containers are still correct, since every container is on the same `networks:`.  (You could simplify the Compose file by deleting all of the `networks:` blocks and using the Compose-provided `default` network, which I believe will still be an overlay network if it's deploying to Docker Swarm.)

Comment: But I still dont get how API requests sent to port 9854 by nodejs app ends up at port 9090 specified by wsgi (its the django container providing REST APIs).

Comment: If the browser application (outside of Docker) sends to `http://localhost:9854` it arrives at the HAProxy container, which should be listening on port 80.  That needs to have configuration forwarding to `http://wsgi:9090`.  The HAProxy piece is critical in this and I'd look at its configuration.

Comment: (You'll often see similar configurations that use Nginx as a reverse proxy in the same place in the stack.)

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case. I never dabbled haproxy in the config earlier. I felt every port information will be defined in the docker compose file itself. Now, I just checked `haproxy.cfg` and it has three consecutive lines: `backend api`,`balance roundrobin` and `server wsgi wsgi:9090 check`. Seems this is what you were saying right?!